# UITableView reloadData not working when put it in Editing Did End IBAction, btter know why

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uistoryboard

I put a textfield in every cell of the table. And after editing the textfield, an `EditingDidEnd` Event will trigger. In the method of hanlding this event I try to use

```
[XXXUITableViewController.tableView reloadData];
```

but it doesn't work(the delegate method is not called).

If I try to `reloadData` in someway like hanlding Tapgesture, it works just fine. I can use anthoer way to make my app work, but it's better to know why is reloadData not working. Any ideas, thanks a lot.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ParCellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    for(UIView * old in cell.contentView.subviews){
        [old removeFromSuperview];
    }  

    //add a textfield in Table Cell View
    ParticleConfigCellView * parCell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ParticleConfigCellView" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];       
    [parCell refreshFromDataSource:[self.dataContainer.data_particleConifig objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];        
    [cell.contentView addSubview:parCell];

    return cell;
}


 - (IBAction)nameChange:(id)sender {

        [self savedata];
        [self.tableView reloadData];//(not working. Table view delegate methods are not called.)
    }
```

Comment: You say the delegate method isn't working, not `reloadData`. Show code where you set the delegate and the delegate method implementation.

Comment: I setup the delegate by draging the UITableViewController in the stroyboard. Use an embeded segue to load the UITableViewController. I didn't change the default configuration of the UITableViewController cause it's just a simple test projiect.

Comment: the delegate of the text field - that's what you said isn't working right?

Comment: No, reloadData method of the tableview isn't work. Call of reloadData is from an Event( EditingDidEnd Event ) triggered by a textfield which is in the cell of the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in this method also reload your array which is showing in table view because after saving new data you are not reloading new data so that its showing old data only.

```
- (IBAction)nameChange:(id)sender {

        [self savedata];
        [yourArray removeAllObjects];
        //then here put new that in yourArray
        [self.tableView reloadData];//(not working)
    }
```

Edit:

Also call this method `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the last line of your `savedata` method.

Comment: Thanks, this will work. But i also wonder why  [self.tableView reloadData]; not calling tableView's delegate method?

Comment: Not exact what I expected, I may not describe the question very well i think.

Comment: Now tell me what will happning?? what you want did you link table view delegate??

Comment: When I call [UITableView reloadData], it will call delegate method such as :- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView. But those delegate methods are not called. That's the problem.

Comment: i will definatly help you if you show me how you implimenting table view delegate

Answer (score 0):

Each time you create a cell, you must assign a delegate text field that is in it. If you are using a dynamic table, add this code `cell.yourTextField.delegate = self` in this method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Or maybe you forgot to subscribe your class to the protocol?

In any case, the method `reloadData` updates the data in the table from its data source, and I do not understand why you need to call this method after you enter text in a field that is in the table. If you don't save this text, it will disappear after call `reloadData` method.

Comment: I do save data before reloadData. And when I call reloadData in some other place, it works fine. I try to call reloadData in a 0.1s delay at - (IBAction)nameChange:(id)sender{}, it also works fine. Strangely, just can not call it directly.